# Detect change in UIAppearance proxy for custom button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uiappearance

I am creating a custom button and it has a couple of properties that are marked as `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`.  How can I detect when the property is changed through the appearance proxy?  The property setter is not called.

The property does get changed, because it has the correct value in `drawRect:`, but I still need to detect when it gets changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using KVO (Key-Value Observer). I'm not putting any code here, because it's really important to read the docs and understand the concept before using it.
From Apple's Key-Value Observing Programming Guide:

> Key-value observing provides a mechanism that allows objects to be notified of changes to specific properties of other objects.

[Here is the link for the official documentation from Apple.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)